# Cuando una clase hereda de otra ¿también hereda sus decoradores?

Tags: python-3.x, poo, herencia, decoradores

En el siguiente código, ¿es necesario volver a colocar el decorador `@classmethod` en la clase `HeredandoDeInterfaz` en el método `metodo_abstracto_de_clase`?

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Clase(ABC):
    @classmethod
    @abstractmethod
    def metodo_abstracto_de_clase(cls):
        pass

class HeredandoDeInterfaz:
    def __init__(self):
        self.hola = "Said"

    @classmethod
    def metodo_abstracto_de_clase(cls):
        print(f"Hola {cls.hola}, soy un  metodo de clase y un metodo abstracto")

Objeto = HeredandoDeInterfaz()
Objeto.metodo_abstracto_de_clase()
```

Ya que si no lo coloco puedo acceder a los atributos de `HeredandoDeInterfaz` cosa que creo que no debería pasar ¿o es mala práctica colocar dos veces `@classmethod`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te falta heredar de `Clase`, pero supongo que es solo un error tipográfico:

```
class HeredandoDeInterfaz(Clase):
    ...                   #####
```

En cuanto a los decoradores y la herencia. Lo primero es tener claro que un decorador no es mas que azúcar sintáctica para una función que retorna otra función, es decir:

```
class Clase(ABC):
    @classmethod
    @abstractmethod
    def metodo_abstracto_de_clase(cls):
        pass
```

y

```
class Clase(ABC):
    def metodo_abstracto_de_clase(cls):
        pass

    metodo_abstracto_de_clase = classmethod(abstractmethod(metodo_abstracto_de_clase))
```

son lo mismo.

Cuando se ejecuta el modulo en el que defines la clase, se ejecuta `classmethod(abstractmethod(metodo_abstracto_de_clase))` una sola vez. El resultado se asocia al identificador `metodo_abstracto_de_clase`.

Cuando heredas de `Clase` heredas esta función retornada por las funciones decoradoras:

```
class HeredandoDeInterfaz(Clase):
    def __init__(self):
        self.hola = "Said"
```

Si intentamos instanciar la clase:

```
>>> HeredandoDeInterfaz()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class HeredandoDeInterfaz without an implementation for abstract method 'metodo_abstracto_de_clase'
```

veremos el resultado de la envoltura llevada a cabo por `abstractmethod`, igual que podemos comprobar como el método es un método de clase (es un método asociado, *bound method*, a la clase):

```
>>> HeredandoDeInterfaz.metodo_abstracto_de_clase
<bound method Clase.metodo_abstracto_de_clase of <class '__main__.HeredandoDeInterfaz'>>
```

La cosa esta en que cuando tu sobrescribes un método o atributo lo que haces es realmente es substituirlo, simplemente asocias el identificador (`metodo_abstracto_de_clase` en este caso) a otro objeto. Python para bien o para mal da una libertad enorme en cuanto a lo que puedes hacer, por ejemplo:

```
class HeredandoDeInterfaz(Clase):
    def __init__(self):
        self.hola = "Said"

    metodo_abstracto_de_clase = "Hola"

obj = HeredandoDeInterfaz()
```

y el interprete te dirá "por mi bien, tu sabrás lo que haces...".

Por lo tanto, el "efecto" del decorador se pierde totalmente cuando sobreescribes un método decorado en una clase padre. Volver a decorar el método en la clase hija no es que sea mala practica, es que es lo normal si quieres que el método siga siendo un método de clase en ella y no un método de instancia. En realidad no estas decorando de nuevo nada, el método que defines en la clase hija es otro objeto, de hecho puedes llamar al método padre con `super().metodo_abstracto_de_clase()`, lo cual a veces tiene sentido incluso en este caso, ya que un *abstractmethod* en Python puede tener implementación.

Comment: Ósea que lo único de lo que se asegura Python es que  `metodo_abstracto_de_clase`
este asociado a algo y al asociarlo a ese algo estoy creando un nuevo objeto y por lo tanto al ser otro objeto diferente no tiene los decoradores de el método `metodo_abstracto_de_clase` de la clase padre ¿es correcto?

Comment: A grandes rasgos si. He editado la respuesta profundizando algo mas en que pasa por debajo con la esperanza de no liar mas al que la lea... Es un tema complejo porque no solo implica comprender  como Python busca los atributos cuando se usa la notacion punto (objeto.atributo), sino que también hay que tener en cuenta temas como el MRO o los descriptores y cada uno de ellos da para escribir mucho a poco que se profundice.

Comment: Si entiendo, profundizas un poquito en lo que pasa por detrás del lenguaje y por más mínimo que sea se desata un infierno de información jajajajaja.
Pero bueno muchas gracias por tu ayuda y suerte.